# Using writeOGR with rpy2

Tags: r, rpy2

I am trying to use writeOGR using R called from Python 3.8.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

.....
ro.r('ttops <- .....')
ro.r('writeOGR(obj=ttops, dsn="T:/Internal/segmentation", layer="test", driver="ESRI Shapefile")')
```

errors with:

```
R[write to console]: Error in writeOGR(obj = ttops, dsn = "T:/Internal/LiDAR/crown_segmentation",  : 
  could not find function "writeOGR"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/david/PycharmProjects/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/david/PycharmProjects/main.py", line 4, in main
    R_Packages().process()
  File "C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\model_testing\r_methods.py", line 17, in process
    ro.r('writeOGR(obj=ttops, dsn="T:/Internal/segmentation", layer="test", driver="ESRI Shapefile")')
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 416, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 197, in __call__
    return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 125, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\conversion.py", line 44, in _
    cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface.py", line 624, in __call__
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in writeOGR(obj = ttops, dsn = "T:/Internal/segmentation",  : 
  could not find function "writeOGR"
```

Am I missing something or is this a limit of rpy2? If it is a limit, what is an alternative to write shapefiles of R data using Python?

Comment: you do have GDAL installed, don't you?

Comment: I just upgraded to python 3.8. pip install gdal errored. Will open new topic for that and inform if that solves previous issue.

Comment: Grab the binary [gdal](https://gdal.org/download.html)

Comment: sorry, I downloaded 3.1.2 and unpacked. Where should it live/ do I need to reference it in environment variables?

Comment: I'm ubuntu, been years since I built windows. I'd go with the binary and get my r2py working.

Answer (score 0):

There was a library that I did not need to define in R that was needed in Python:

```
ro.r('library(rgdal)')
```